# Can't resolve 'react-native' in my project

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I made the tutorial small project from React official site and when I tried using some native react components such as Text and ImageBackground and I get compilation error of:

Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in ...

I created my project with "npx create-react-app".

That the import I made.

```
import { Text, ImageBackground } from 'react-native'
```

I tried doing npm install and npm install 'react-native-elements' and so on... nothing worked.

Anyway here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tutorial",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have react-native in your dependencies, please do an npm i react-native

Comment: Already did that. Didn't work.

Comment: then please update your package.json

Comment: I did npm install react-native and then npm update and npm install, but it still shows the error.

Comment: you can't create react native project using 'create-react-app'. please check https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Comment: Oh.. Isn't react-native a module that you can import?

Comment: yes. it is a module but react used for web & react-native used for mobile and you can't create a react native project using react web app.

Comment: First of all I didn't know you can develop android/ios apps with react, nice to know that. 
Second, so I can't use the components I see in:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator
?
Third, why can I use button, isn't that one of the native ones?

Answer (score 0):

React projects and React Native projects are different.
You have to use [**React Native CLI**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

To create a new react-native project run this command from your cmd / terminal:

```
react-native init
```

The reason why you are facing this issue is that the required modules are not included in your **package.json**. Once you run the above mentioned command the `npm` will install all the required dependencies that are needed for your project.
The command that you have mentioned in your question doesn’t do what’s expected.

Answer (score 0):

**For React Native Mobile App**

Using this command to create react native project android and ios application.

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

You need some other configuration also to run this project like node.js,android studio, android sdk and xcode for ios. You can follow this link for more detail.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

**For React Web App**

`npx create-react-app` above command is used for react native web app.